# iOS - Slide menu into a UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, menu, tableview

I would like to create a side menu:
 how do I put it in an `UITableViewController`? 
The problem is that I have another `ViewController` before the `TableView` (that of the login screen) and I can not use `SWRevealViewController` because this class assumes that it is the first one running while I login. 
How do I create a menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Start by adding a 2 ViewControllers to your storyboard.
2. Make one `ViewController`'s class `SWRevealViewController`
3. The other `ViewController` will be your side menu make it a custom class.
4. Create a `custom segue` from `SWRevealViewController` to your `HamburgerViewController`
5. Select the `custom segue` change the `identifier` property to `sw_right`
6. Now create another `custom segue` from the `SWRevealViewController` to your `UITableViewController`
7. Select the `custom segue` change the `identifier` property to `sw_front`
8. Your `ViewController` that appears before the `UITableViewController` should perform a `segue` to the `SWRevealViewController`instead of the `UITableViewController` directly.

You can also find multiple tutorials here: https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController